# Ext js migration from 3 to 4 - ComboBox crashes application

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am migrating Ext js from 3.x to the new 4.0.2a. Seems that everything in my project works fine except of comboboxes. It doesn't really matter where i use a combobox, but it keeps crashing my application on launch.

the error im getting is: **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

Here is an example of my code (login page with combobox):

index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext3-core-compat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext3-compat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/My.Viewport.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/My.LoginWindow.js"></script>
```

app.js:

```
Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = '/ext/resources/images/default/s.gif';
Ext.ns('My');

My.Base = function (){

   Ext.QuickTips.init();

   return {
       init: function () {

           var win = Ext.create('My.LoginWindow',{
              title: 'Authorization',
              callback: function(){
                   new Dag.Viewport();
               }
           });
           win.show();
       }
   }
}();
Ext.onReady(My.Base.init, My.Base);
```

My.LoginWindow.js:

```
Ext.define('My.LoginWindow', {

extend:'Ext.Window',
//alias: 'widget.LoginWindow', This is not required.
initComponent: function(){

    Ext.define('test', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['abbr', 'name']
    });

    var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'test',
        data : [
            {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
            {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
            {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
        ]
    });

    this.form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{

        baseCls: 'x-plain',
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        defaults: {
            labelWidth: 55,
            allowBlank: false,
            anchor:'100%'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'combobox',
            fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
            store: states,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'abbr'
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Account',
            name: 'account'
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Login',
            name: 'login'
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Password',
            name: 'password',
            inputType: 'password',
            listeners: {
                'specialkey': function(field, e){
                    if (e.getKey() == 13){
                        this.submitForm();
                    }
                },
                scope: this
            }
        }]
    });

    Ext.apply(this, {
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        closable: false,
        plain: true,
        width: 200,
        draggable: false,
        bodyStyle:'padding:5px;',
        items: this.form,
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Login',
            handler: this.submitForm,
            scope: this
        },{
            text: 'Cancel',
            handler: function(){
                this.form.getForm().reset();
            },
            scope: this
        }]
    });
    this.callParent(arguments);

},

submitForm: function(){
    var f = this.form.getForm();

    f.submit({
        url: 'myurl',
        waitMsg: 'Login...',
        waitTitle: 'Wait',
        scope: this,
        success: function(form, action){
            this.callback.call();                
            this.close();
        },
        failure: function(form, action){
            var res = action.result;
            var msg = 'Enter correct login and password, please.'

            if (res && res.message){
                msg = res.message;
            }

            Ext.Msg.alert('Error', msg);
        }
    });
}
});
```

As you can see im using a standard combobox with standard data (from sencha's example docs).
When i now launch the application, it crashes with the error message described above.
But when i remove the combobox, the application fully works, i see the login window and can login to show the My.Viewport.

What can cause this error, does some code call itself all the time? I've spend many hours fixing this annoying problem, but no luck so far.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you try replacing the My.LoginWindow.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments); line with "this.callParent()"?

Comment: And actually in Extjs 4, form panel is "Ext.form.Panel" and the syntax to create is "Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel,{});"

Answer (score 0):

I do see some things you still need to update, for example switching the superclass call with callParent, replacing the new X() calls with Ext.create(), etc.  However, nothing jumps out at me that would be causing a stack overflow.  You should probably break on errors in Firebug and do a little debugging to see where the issue is originating.

Comment: okay I changed superclass to callParent(arugments), new X() to Ext.create(), and did some debugging, what i noticed is that the this.callParent() never gets called, it breaks on the following: Ext.define.addListener
Ext.define.bindStore
Ext.define.initComponent
(anonymous function)
Base.callParent
Ext.define.initComponent

Comment: Got it! what I noticed is that I used an custom combobox (Ext.ux.TwinComboBox.js), which worked perfectly in Ext js 3, but not in 4 I suppose. this was causing the stack overflow. Now that everything  works again, I have one more question, does anybody have a reference to website for a TwinComboBox that is working for Ext js 4? Thank you guys for all of your help I really appreciated it.

Comment: Not sure, you'd either have to locate the original author or upgrade that component yourself. I'm not familiar with it.